# group by column and select other column as list in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table like bellow

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
+---+---+
| 2 | 1 |
+---+---+
| 3 | 2 |
+---+---+
| 4 | 2 |
+---+---+
| 5 | 2 |
+---+---+
```

Is there an effective way to query to form like:

```
{1 => [1,2], 2 => [3,4,5]}
```

(group by B and select A as list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `string_agg()` function

```
select B,string_agg(A,', ') 
from tablename
group by B
```

OR you can use `array_agg()`

```
select B,array_agg(A) 
from tablename
group by B
```